# replaceAll(" ", "") removes all text in string after space " "?

Tags: java, replaceall

I'm trying to remove all the spaces in a string using `replaceAll(" ", "")` but any text such as `"hello world"` will remove not only the spaces but the text after the space -- what I mean is that I end up with with just `"hello"` instead of `"helloworld"`. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
            String input;
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("enter text: ");
            input = console.next();
            System.out.println();

            input.replaceAll(" ", "");
            System.out.println(input);
    }
```

Comment: It shouldn't be, I tried just now it's working fine. Can you show us your code? `System.out.println("Hello World".replaceAll(" ", ""));` prints me `HelloWorld`

Comment: Here's a working example http://ideone.com/gGpIIZ

Comment: Are you expecting it to work in place?

Comment: Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/qACPJyp6
And my output: http://screencast.com/t/6MWESfeD

I'm using TextPad FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reassign it to your variable (or to a new one):

```
input = input.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Strings are immutable which means they cannot be altered. What `replaceAll()` does is create a new string. Therefore in order to use it, you have to assign it to a variable.

The reason you are only seeing `Hello` is because you're using `scanner.next()` instead of `scanner.nextLine()`.

The former will only take the first token until the delimiter (standard: whitespace) is reached. The latter will consider an endline character (in windows: `\r\n`, <kbd>enter</kbd>) as its delimiter.

Your working code looks like this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
        String input;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("enter text: ");
        input = console.nextLine(); // Change here
        System.out.println();

        input = input.replaceAll(" ", ""); // Change here
        System.out.println(input);
}
```

Comment: nextLine() did it! Thank you very much!!